# Compose recomposes even though state value does not change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose view with a `LazyList` inside. Above the list I show a text with the offset of the first item in the list.

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp)) {
        val state = rememberLazyListState()

        val offset = state.firstItemOffset
        Text(text = "First item offset: $offset")
        Log.e("tag", "MyComponent() ... drawing with offset $offset")

        LazyRow(state = state) {
            items(100) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                    text = "Item $it"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private val LazyListState.firstItemOffset: Int?
    get() = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == 0 }?.offset
```

I noticed that when i scroll the list, `MyComponent` gets recomposed, even when the first item is off screen and the returned offset is `null` and did not change from the last composition. How could I set this up so it only recomposes when the value actually changes?

Bonus question: why does the `firstItemOffset` getter not need a `@Composable` annotation for it to update? This way, it only returns an int and should not trigger a recompose at all. To be clear, I want it to recompose when the value changes, I just wonder why the annotation is not needed.

Edit:
My guess is that it recomposed because the instance of `layoutInfo` changes on every scroll even though the value returned by `firstItemOffset` stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that the return value of `firstItemOffset` is not a state, but the used `layoutInfo` internally is one. So every time `layoutInfo` changes, a recomposition happens.

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but this works:

```
private val LazyListState.firstItemOffset: Int?
    @Composable get() = remember {
        derivedStateOf { layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == 0 }?.offset }
    }.value
```

Comment: `derivedStateOf` seems to be the solution for your usecase.  Whilst `derivedStateOf { calculation }` will always be called when `state` changes it doesn't inact a recompostion of the scope where this value is read until it changes.  Seems there are quite a few nuances to be aware of with compose ... but I learn't something new to be aware of, it will be especially handy when looking for optimisations.

Comment: Yes there are definitely a lot of new and unexpected nuances to look out for. There is no free lunch i guess ;-) Thanks a lot for your input @Mark